# How to install mongo bi connector in alpine linux?

Tags: alpine-linux, mongodb

How to install mongo bi connector in alpine linux?

the mongo bi connector is the 'mongosqld',https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/

there are debian version, windows and macos version but not alpine version.

how to install it in alpine linux

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

mongodb-bi-connector is not released as opensource project (in that case, it would have been possibile to try to build it for Alpine Linux).

Rather, since it's shipped as a pre-compiled binary, until MongoDB will release an "Alpine Linux" build you can't use it as-is.

The only option in the short term to use mongodb-bi-connector with Alpine Linux is within a container where Alpine Linux is the host, and the container is a supported distribution.